# Google Analytics does not show AdSense if you have multiple sites

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense

I have multiple sites in my Google Analytics, and under the content section, adsense revenue per page is only visible for one of the sites. The rest of the sites in my Google analytics do not display what page the AdSense revenue came from.

Is this a known bug?  Has anyone had this?  Or do I need to configure something else?

**Here is how I currently do this.**

It is constructed as part of a php string, but the idea is the same. See the first 2 lines of this function.  And the rest of the function displays traditional analytics snippet.

```
  $str = '';
    if($production === true)
    {
        $str.= '<script type="text/javascript">'."\n";

        $str.= 'window.google_analytics_uacct = "UA-9425856-20";'."\n";

        $str.= 'var _gaq = _gaq || [];'."\n";
        $str.= '_gaq.push(["_setAccount", "UA-9425856-20"]);'."\n";
        $str.= '_gaq.push(["_trackPageview"]);'."\n";

        $str.= '(function() {'."\n";
        $str.= ' var ga = document.createElement("script"); ga.type = "text/javascript"; ga.async = true;'."\n";
        $str.= ' ga.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://ssl" : "http://www") + ".google-analytics.com/ga.js";'."\n";
        $str.= ' var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);'."\n";
        $str.= '})();'."\n";

        $str.= '</script>'."\n";
    }
    echo $str;
```

Comment: Does anyone know if this works.  I am having trouble getting my adsense to register on all my analytic accounts.

Comment: @Adam I tried to implement the answer below, but it still does not work for me unfortunately.  Anyone else? :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an additional snippet of code to your non-primary domains:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.google_analytics_uacct = "UA-XXXXXX-X";
</script>
```

It needs to be placed above the other GA and AdSense code. The `"UA-XXXXXX-X"` should be replaced with the same GA account number used in the GA code.

Comment: @Ewan Unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: Can you post an example of the code you're using?

Comment: @Ewan I just posted the snipped that is in my code.  Thank you for following up :)

Comment: Try splitting up your code and putting the `window.google_analytics_uacct` bit just below the opening `<body>` tag. Then put the GA tracking code right at the bottom of the page next to the closing `</body>` tag. I know that GA suggests putting it in the head section but it is possible to put at the bottom as well and is sometimes needed for the AdSense tracking to work.

Comment: Did this change make any difference?

Comment: @Ewan I have not had time to try it.  I plan on doing it now (I have a spare 15 min), or Friday or this weekend.  Will report on how it goes :)

Comment: @Ewan by the way, did you mean that I should take the    window.google_analytics_uacct line out of the main analytics snippet?

Comment: @Ewan Just added this <script type="text/javascript">
 window.google_analytics_uacct = "my_code";
</script> to 2 pages, one right below the opening body tag and one right above the closing body tag.  Lets see what happens :) How long do you think it should take to work?

Comment: @Ewan you know, that seems to not have worked either :(

Comment: What's the URL your trying it on?

Comment: @Ewan http://www.comehike.com